# Sort cards according to their suites and values using python

Tags: python, sorting, playing-cards

Can anybody help me to sort the cards by suite and value?
I have:

```
list_cards = [('♥', '9'), ('♥', 'J'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♥', '7'), ('♥', '10'), ('♦', '10')]
```

and I need to get:

```
[('♥', '7'), ('♥', '9'), ('♥', '10'),('♥', 'J'), ('♦', '10'), ('♦', 'J')]
```

I tried such methods:

```
return list_cards.sort(key=lambda c: (NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]], c[1]))
return sorted(list_cards, key=lambda c: (NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]], c[1]))
return sorted(list_cards)
```

and so on...

but the result differs from that I wanted to get.
Here is the full code:

```
NOMINALS = ['7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
NAME_TO_VALUE = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(NOMINALS)} -> :<class 'dict'>: {'7': 0, '8': 1, '9': 2, '10': 3, 'J': 4, 'Q': 5, 'K': 6, 'A': 7}
list_cards = [('♥', '9'), ('♥', 'J'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♥', '7'), ('♥', '10'), ('♦', '10')]

def sort_hand():
    # return list_cards.sort(key=lambda c: (NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]], c[1]))
    # return sorted(list_cards, key=lambda c: (NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]], c[1]))
    return sorted(list_cards)
```

Comment: hi perhaps use `NAME_TO_VALUE[c[1]]` which is the cardinal value (instead of `c[0]` which is the suit`).

Comment: That's a strange sorting scheme by the way, ascending suits are normally spades, clubs, diamonds and hearts. At least for all the games I've played where suits are ordered, which is probably 0.0000001% of all the card games in the world :-)

Comment: if I use `NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]]` then I get `KeyError: '♥'` like for other types of methods which I used. in case of `NAME_TO_VALUE[c[0]]` I get `None`

Comment: also the way of sorting does not matter))) It's just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One* way is to simply use helper functions to convert cards to and from ordinal positions, then use those ordinal positions for sorting.

For example:

```py
# These decide sort order, change if different order needed.

suitMap = ['♠', '♣', '♦', '♥']
faceMap = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

def cardToOrd(cardVal):
    return 13 * suitMap.index(cardVal[0]) + faceMap.index(cardVal[1])

def ordToCard(ordVal):
    return (suitMap[ordVal // 13], faceMap[ordVal % 13])

def sortCards(cardList):
    newList = [cardToOrd(i) for i in cardList]
    newList.sort()
    return [ordToCard(i) for i in newList]

cards = [('♥', '9'), ('♥', 'J'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♥', '7'), ('♥', '10'), ('♦', '10')]
print(cards)
print(sortCards(cards))
```

You could make it a little more robust if there's a chance invalid cards may be used. Changing the ordinal conversion functions as per below will force invalid cards to `('?', '?')` and place them at the end:

```py
def cardToOrd(cardVal):
    try:
        return 13 * suitMap.index(cardVal[0]) + faceMap.index(cardVal[1])
    except:
        return 99999

def ordToCard(ordVal):
    try:
        return (suitMap[ordVal // 13], faceMap[ordVal % 13])
    except:
        return ('?', '?')
```

---

As an aside, this is probably something I'd put into a class (e.g., `cardset` or `deck`), so I could collect all card processing code into a single coherent object. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Thx a lot, BRO! that works perfect! I spent several hours but failed and you provided me the answer within 10 mins since I posted it))))

Comment: @Vladimir, since you're such a nice guy, I've made changes to make it handle `10` instead of `T` :-)

Comment: thx for assistance! really appreciate it :-)

Comment: This is the only way to go. Strings are for humans. Computers represent things with numbers. Just convert to/from strings for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a couple dictionaries that store the order of the suits and ranks that you want, assuming you know the cards will be valid:

```
SUITS = ['♥', '♦', '♠', '♣']
RANKS = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
SUIT_ORDER = {suit: order for order, suit in enumerate(SUITS)}
RANK_ORDER = {rank: order for order, rank in enumerate(RANKS)}

list_cards = [('♥', '9'), ('♥', 'J'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♥', '7'), ('♥', '10'), ('♦', '10'), ('♠', '6'), ('♣', 'A')]
sorted_list_cards = sorted(list_cards, key=lambda c: (SUIT_ORDER[c[0]], RANK_ORDER[c[1]]))
print(sorted_list_cards)
```

**Output:**

```
[('♥', '7'), ('♥', '9'), ('♥', '10'), ('♥', 'J'), ('♦', '10'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♣', 'A'), ('♠', '6')]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping! this code also resolves my issue!)